# Programming with wget and saving file into memory

Tags: c, http, pointers, wget

I am programming in C and require that I downloaded a webpage. I am currently using wget to download, although I wish to save the file in memory and allocate a pointer to it in order to read the file downloaded.

In it's current state my application  `uses popen(/usr/bin/wget http://www.website.com, "w");`
I then allocate a `FILE *file = fopen("index.html", "rt");`

Is this possible with `wget`? and if not, are they are alternatives?

Comment: It is possible, but invoking command line tools for doing subtasks is considered a hack. Just use libcurl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an API you will be better served by [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). Start with the [easy interface](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-easy.html) to begin with.